# Flexbox distributing not equaly in column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the title centered between two lines.
For now, the bottom padding is too small.

[image: my actual result]

```css
.carousseltitle {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 75vw;
  height: 10vw;
  font-size: 5vw;
  margin-top: 48vw;
  text-align: center;
}

#line {
  width: 75vw;
  /* color: linear-gradient(89deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70) 53.13%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%); */
  background-image: linear-gradient(89deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70) 53.13%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(89deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70) 53.13%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%);
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousseltitle">
  <hr id="line"> Mon super projet
  <hr id="line">
</div>
```

Comment: note that IDs have to be unique. You can't reuse an id and assign them to multiple elements

Comment: Thank you, I've just change the ID for a class

Answer (score 0):

modify your CSS to the code below:

```
.carousseltitle {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
font-size: 5vw;
}

#line {
width: 100%;
}
```

and by the way, the way you're setting your units for yous css properties is a bad practice...

and for the background image you should add a `url()` so the image can be applied.